# Когда надо обрабатывать исключения, а когда пробрасывать выше?

Tags: java, исключения, java-8

Всегда интересовал вопрос. Вот есть метод, в котором может возникнуть проверяемое исключение. Мы можем либо обработать его прямо внутри метода, либо пробросить выше. Я всегда делал это наугад, то есть где-то проброшу, где-то обработаю. Но почему-то всегда казалось, что если этот метод маленький, то исключение лучше пробросить. Или же если этот метод не вызывает другие методы, а просто выполняет какое-то действие. Из всего этого у меня возник вопрос, а есть ли какие-нибудь стандарты, когда стоит пробрасывать исключение, а когда обрабатывать? Просто чисто фактически исключение так можно пробросить и до метода main. Так вот, как определить, когда следует пробрасывать исключение выше, а когда стоит его обрабатывать?

Comment: Если вы знаете что делать с исключением(как решить проблему) обрабатывайте на месте. Если не знаете как решить эту проблему (или это невозможно) пробрасывайте выше

Comment: @igo то есть если у меня допустим есть метод, который производит чтение из файла и при этом может выкинуть IOException, то мне лучше прям сразу же в этом методе обработать это исключение?

Comment: это тот случай когда вы нечего не можете сделать (так как файла может не быть, или отсутствуют права на его чтение или еще что то)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того на каком уровне вы хотите их обрабатывать.

Ну например у вас нет сущность которая отвечает за запросы в сеть и вторая сущность, отвечающая за запросы в базу данных. И все эти запросы дергаются из какой-то вашей View. Откуда в этой ситуации лучше обрабатывать?

Если, к примеру, вся ваша обработка заключается в том чтобы просто вывести ошибку в лог, то не стоит эти ошибки куда-то пробрасывать, а обработать прямо там.

Но чаще вы захотите показать пользователю какое-то сообщение или другое View, в общем как-то отреагировать в вашем UI. Тогда стоит пробросить ошибку в слой View.

Это самые простые и очевидные способы обработки, но есть и более продвинутые. Например вы можете обрабатывать ваши ошибки непосредственно в том месте где они возникают, а там их оборачивать в какую-то обёртку (в Kotlin для этого очень хорошо подходит sealed class), и возвращать уже эту обёртку с результатом и в зависимости от результата ваш UI может реагировать по разному.

Здесь можно почитать подходы к обработке ошибок
https://m.habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/471766/